# SendObject in MSAccess giving errors

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

I am getting the following error while sending mail using a button in MS access form

I am using sendObject to send mail using vba code.

The host 'smtp' could not be found. Please verify that you have entered the server name correctly. Account: 'pop3', Server: 'smtp', Protocol: SMTP, Port: 25, Secure(SSL): No, Socket Error: 11001, Error Number: 0x800CCC0D

Please help

I know that, this is a smtp settings problem. But where should i check this ... is this in my outlook client or is there anywhere the settings are configured in the code ?

Comment: Might be a little easier to troubleshoot this if you include some code.

Answer (score 1):

SendObject is so basic there is nothing for you to configure outside of your default email provider.  Which you've stated is Outlook.  Check the default profile.

Also see [SendObject's twenty limitations](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/email/sendobject.htm) and the [Microsoft Access Email FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/email.htm) fpr alternatives to SendObject if required.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you get past this error, there are several more limitations involved with SendObject. It's almost not even worth running this particular approach down. I would suggest taking a look at [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/). I have had excellent results from this library for many years.